# Multiple environment on Same RabbitMQ server possible?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am thinking of setting of single rabbit mq on *inx box. Is it possible to open up two ports in such a way, for one development environement we go one port and for QA environment go to different post still use single box and single instance of Rabbit MQ. Is this possible?
Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Vhost configuration of RabbitMQ to distinguish different environments.
When creating connections you need to make sure that in addition to the hostname and exchange that you also specify a vhost.

Note that there are no tcp port differences, you still connect on 5672, it's purely an additional piece of connection metadata rather than a transport level difference.